# Why will an auto-reload make a browser crash? How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, refresh, reload

I made an auto reload script in Chrome and it goes like this:

```
if (window.location.toString() === 'http://blabla.com/yup')
{
    setTimeout(function (){
                           window.location.reload(true);
                          },2000);
}
```

This script runs after the page is fully loaded and I don't think it goes too fast. It does what it should do, but why will this end up making the browser crash after a while? What makes a browser crash happen in this situation?

Probably my main question: how do I make an auto-refresh that doesn't make the browser crash?

-

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd need to reload a whole page...every 2 seconds. Either way, you could not reload the whole page and only get the necessary **data** with AJAX, "reloading" areas of the page

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to programming and I tried doing that but I didn't figure out how to make it work. But most importantly, how does that affect why a browser would crash? What makes the browser crash? Saving up too much data or something?

Answer (score 0):

For every 2 sec. re-loading, this simple old code should do the trick.

**This is old but works on auto self:**

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" content="2;URL=http://blabla.com/yup">
```

It is an old code, but it usually works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Also more advanced but fully working without crashing your browser.

**Use this with target `_self` or what ever you want:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open('http://blabla.com/yup', '_self');", 2000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

**Or this with automatic self and no target code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://blabla.com/yup';", 2000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

Both do the same thing, but in the 1 code you can target it, wile in the second code it will always replace the existing page.